# Authorizing users based on Windows Authentication matching ID in Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, windows-authentication

I am currently building an ASP.NET MVC application that requires only certain users to access. I am using Windows Authentication and I want to grant access to users whose `User.Identity.Name` matches with the `LogonID` inside the `AdminUsers` table. What I would like to know is what would be the best way to go about it?

If you need anymore information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @teovankot glad we cleared that up, so how do you go about it?

Comment: teo van kot- Considering the kind of knowledge you have, we expect a little more brief answer. can you please share with us.